# Can pdfHTML handle dynamically generated HTML content?

Tags: itext, itext7, html-pdf

I have a use-case in which i need to generate PDF dynamically using iText7.

I have sample Landing page which accepts a url-encoded parameter id

> www.example.com/mypage.html?id=1

At the time of page load an ajax call gets triggered and some html gets rendered dynamically through jquery based on that url parameter.

I have to use using webpage link((www.example.com/mypage.html?id=1)) for converting HTML to PDF.

https://git.itextsupport.com/users/bruno/repos/htmlsamples/browse/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/htmlsamples/chapter07

Can I convert the dynamically generated HTML(HTML Generated after ajax call) to PDF using IText7?

Comment: If you can't do it directly in IText, this might be helpful:  https://wkhtmltopdf.org/

Answer (score 0):

Former iText employee here.

`pdfHTML` can not (at the point of writing) handle dynamically generated content.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: Can itext5 with flying saucer handle above case? https://labs.tadigital.com/index.php/2018/04/23/generating-pdf-from-html-in-adobe-experience-manager-6-1

Comment: @ShridharSahu That is material for a new question (however, I can already tell you that the answer is also no).